# Want to wipe and donate very old mac - but no original disc

Tags: imac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Two older Macs (G3 / Intel) need their drives erased. No install discs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73999/two-older-macs-g3-intel-need-their-drives-erased-no-install-discs)

I have a mac from 2002 or so, and want to wipe it and give it away.  No idea where the original disk is.  Any idea how to wipe it?

Comment: Could you bring it to a local repair shop and ask if they might have discs to wipe it clean with?

Comment: There's still torrents for old versions of OS X.

Comment: If it has a firmware password - [look here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36904/how-to-wipe-a-thoroughly-secured-old-computer). If it's a different Mac than this one, please edit the question to make it different than [this case](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73999/two-older-macs-g3-intel-need-their-drives-erased-no-install-discs) and flag for reopening.